# How to execute activate and deactivate methods of OSGI bundle in a single thread

Tags: java, concurrency, osgi

I have an OSGI bundle of a following structure:

```
//...

public ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

//...

@Activate
public void activate() {
   executor.submit(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
      //call 3 functions and log the data
     }
   }
}

@Deactivate
public void deactivate(){
  //call 2 other functions
}
```

The executor in the activate method makes sure that 3 functions are called in a separate from all other bundles thread, because those functions actually implement some sophisticated Windows-message-loop, i.e. a while true loop, that's why, in order not to block other bundles, it is activated in a separate thread. Now what I've sadly noticed, that in order to run 2 functions in deactivate method I need to run them in the same thread, in which 3 functions in activate method were run. Simply speaking, I need to be sure, that activate and deactivate methods of my bundle run in the one same thread, but still to keep this bundle activation separated (in an own thread) from the other bundles.

My question is: how to implement this?

I am not a guru in concurrency in Java, I've tried simply to call this executor in the deactivate method too but I don't know how to do it with one Runnable task, since in deactivate I have only to call 2 functions and in activate only 3 functions and no other calls should be made.

**UPD**: sorry, I forgot to mention, that there is a routine in another bundle, which calls in certain situations `context.getBundle(0).stop()` in order to call a deactivation for all bundles. If I want just to add the same submit routine in the deactivate method as is in activate, then in such situation I could clearly see, that those 2 functions from deactivate method of my bundle in the submit's body were not called.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do another executor.submit in deactivate. As it is a single threaded executor it will make sure only one thread processes both.

The only question is how to shut down the executor reliably. Normally after deactivate a component should have closed all its resources.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. Actually, that was my initial try. The problem is, that there is a routine in another bundle, which calls `context.getBundle(0).stop()` in order to call a deactivation for all bundles. In such a situation I receive a warning in eclipse:
`Deactivating gp.osgi.executor.internal.PoolingExecutor`
and I could clearly see, that those 2 functions from deactivate method of my bundle in the `submit`'s body were not called. Sorry, I should mention it in OP-post

Comment: In your deactivate, after submitting the runnable to run the 2 methods, call `executor.awaitTermination(...)` with some appropriate timeout to wait for the runnable to complete before returning from the deactivate method.

Comment: Yes .. makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a very common problem. I would just make it explicit you're using a thread and use the methods in Thread that were designed for this. At activate you start the thread, at deactivate you interrupt it. Your main loop watches the interrupt status and executes your deactivate functions after it is interrupted. After interrupt, it is best to join the thread to ensure your `activate()` method does not return before the background thread has finished running your deactivate functions.

Since exiting the framework (stopping bundle 0) must stop all bundles, and a stopped bundle will deactivate its components, this should all work.

```
 public class Foo extends Thread {

      @Activate   void activate()   { start(); }
      @Deactivate void deactivate() throws Exception { interrupt(); join(); }

      public void run() {

            while(!isInterrupted()) try {
              ... your 3 function loop
            } catch( InterruptedException e) {
              break;
            }
            ... 2 deactivate functions
      }
  }
```